# How do i read data from a local SQL database in visual basic? The database was made in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, vba, visual-studio-2012

I am having a few issues regarding reading data from a local sql server in visual basic. I have made the database and connected it as a data source but for some reason my data source connection and initial catalog must be incorrect. This is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim rd As SqlDataReader

        con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog=Database1Dataset; Integrated security=true ")
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "select login, password from Table where login = '" & tboxUname.Text & "' and password = '" & tboxPword.Text & "' "
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rd.HasRows Then
            frmProperties.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect Login") 'Else, display a message saying "incorrect login".
            Tries += 1
            If Tries = 3 Then
                MsgBox("Closing Program")
                Close()
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

My database is called Database1 and the table is called Table. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If your database is called `Database1`, you need to change the value for `Initial Catalog` from `Database1Dataset` to `Database1`.

Comment: `tboxUname` = `; sp_msforeachtable('DROP TABLE ?')`

Comment: @Gareth: [Exploits Of A Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/).